# IBM Watson Assistant: How to obtain and print JSON using ASP.NET SDK?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I have successfully fetched data from the IBM Watson Assistant Api using their ASP.NET SDK (which comes equipped with helper functions), but using Response.Write with the data prints out the data as a string and not json.

```
AssistantService assistant = new AssistantService(
    username, 
    password,
    version_date
);
var results = assistant.ListLogs(workspace_id);
Response.Write(results);
```

[image: Visual view of the printed data, which is in string (which I want in json)]

The other SDKs I have tried are the NodeJs and Python ones, for NodeJs I have both printed it out on the browser and console, Python only on console and these 3 scenarios the data has been printed out correctly as json, for e.g. this is some of the data logged in Python:

[image: data printed in console (python)]

Would anyone know why I have this issue? Is it because of Response.Write(?) (Not sure if it messes up the json formatting or something), because the Nodejs and Python SDKs work I am not sure what's wrong when I implement it in ASP.NET.

The IBM Watson Assistant API SDK documentation for ASP.NET is here:
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk

I would really appreciate any kind of help, this is the second day I have been stuck on this issue, I have to work with the data but if it is fetched as a string I can't do anything with it.

Comment: what is the code snippet in question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include code as text rather than image. Code samples are so much more readable than screenshots.

Comment: Shit I changed to traditional mode and forgot to add the code snippet.

Comment: Have added the code. Just 3 statements.

Comment: AssistantService is from: Using IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.Assistant.v1;

Comment: Have printed once in browser and once in console for the NodeJs SDK, worked fine both in json. Done once in console with Python, worked fine logged in json. Only in ASP.NET is the data printed as string. I'm not sure if Response.Write is somehow 'converting'(?) the json data to a string?

Comment: Either remove the question or put your solution into an answer

Answer (score 0):

Never mind solved. Response.Write converted my JSON into a string first before outputting it to browser, tried using Debug.Write and my JSON was printed out into the console correctly.